# How do I create mysql+pymysql engine with time_zone configured?

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, timezone, pymysql

I use SQLAlchemy with pymysql driver to connect to MySQL instance.  This MySQL instance have its timezone configured as UTC.

Now, I want to execute a long SQL query (it is a hard coded SQL script...) which make heavy use of date functions against timestamp columns.  I want this SQL to be executed under my country's local timezone (namely, it is `+09:00`).

#### Question

- When you are making engine with pymysql driver, is it possible to set time_zone other than the server timezone?

  - Or at least, on certain connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See how to pass [Custom DBAPI connect() arguments](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html#custom-dbapi-connect-arguments) for example of how to get past the SQLAlchemy part of what you are trying to do.

There is an open feature request in pymysql repo for what you want: [Allow specifiying a timezone for connections](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/issues/624).

The [`pymysql.connections.Connection`](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/connections.html#module-pymysql.connections) object accepts a parameter called `init_command` for which the docs state:

> Initial SQL statement to run when connection is established.

A contributor provides the following example in the discussion of that issue:

```
init_command="SET SESSION time_zone='+00:00'"
```

So your `create_engine` might look something like this:

```
engine = create_engine(..., connect_args={"init_command": "SET SESSION time_zone='+09:00'"})
```

Comment: SQLAlchemy version: 1.4.39
MySQL Connector version: 8.0.26

engine = create_engine(mysql_url,
                       pool_size=int(pool_size,
                       pool_recycle=3600,
                       pool_pre_ping=True,
                       isolation_level='READ COMMITTED',
                       encoding='utf-8',
                       connect_args={"time_zone": '+08:00'})