# Set timezone when using pandas read_sql and SQLAlchemy engine

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, timezone

While using pymysql driver, we are first executing `set time_zone= <timezone>` on cursor and then the query.
We want to use same time zone while using read_sql and sqlalchemy_engine while selecting data as dataframe.
Is it possible to set the timezone while using pd.read_sql?
Or can timezone be set while creating sqlalchemy_engine?

Answer (score 1):

Got a solution for MySQL in [How do I create mysql+pymysql engine with time_zone configured?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57397982/how-do-i-create-mysqlpymysql-engine-with-time-zone-configured?rq=1)
However, same/similar approach is not working for PostgreSQL. As a workaround, I using a wrapper on read_sql and modifying the incoming query by adding set timezone statement just before the incoming query and that is working without any issue. But I am not sure if this is the best solution or not.